# Garage Power is low...any way to boost?

Tags: batteries, surge-protection, low-battery

First of all, I'm an active StackOverflow user.  This is my first time on Electrical engineering, and I HOPE this is the right place to ask this.

I just moved into a new apartment.  The breakerbox is no where to be seen sadly.  My wife to be has told me that the garage is mine to do with as I please.  So far I have placed a 46inch tv (sony bravia, older LCD, not LED), ps3, several other game systems, high powered computer, low powered HTPC, a small soundbar with sub and a couple of lamps in there.  Everything is hooked up to the one outlet that is available to my setup.  My AVR/batterybackup displays that it is receiving 121-122V.  I have no way to convert to 220 so far as I can tell, and even if I did, I doubt my apartment management would like that very much.

[My AVR/Battery backup](http://reviews.bestbuy.com/3545/8280969/geek-squad-875va-ups-battery-back-up-system-reviews/reviews.htm)

**Problem:**  I currently have the tv, high powered computer (core-i5 oced to 3.8ghz, gefore 560ti448, 750W power supply, and 1 lamp on.  The AVR is reading that it is at 70% capacity. With the ps3 on, playing a netflix video, and   When I start a benchmark on the PC, it jumps to 101-105% of its capacity, and in 5 seconds, shuts itself off.  The breaker has not blown, Im sure because the AVR is absorbing the overflow and not tripping it.

**Question:**  Is there anyway that I could increase the ability to power my garage without major modifications?  For instance, dropping an extension cord down from the upstairs that is on another circuit is doable (fire and electrical codes not withstanding); but adding a sub-box to my breaker box is not.  Im hoping there is a better way, for instance, would piggy backing a couple of higher powered AVR/battery backup units do the trick?

**Current Load information:**

- Computer (basic browsing)and  monitor+1 lamp: **33% - 0.173kW**
- Same as above with TV: **64% - 0.336kW**
- Same as above with PS3 - **85% 0.430kW**
- Computer (running benchmark)and  monitor+1 lamp: **65% - 0.362kW**

Thank you all for any advice/knowledge you can impart.  And again, if this is not the correct subsite for this question, please let me know, or feel free to move it (if you are a mod)

Comment: Just to clarify, you are measuring power, so it is measured in kW (1000 W).  kWh is a measure of energy (kW x time) - the units in which the power company will be billing you for running all of your toys.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The outlet in your garage will either be 15A or 20A, depending on the upstream breaker (hint: it's worth your trouble to find the breaker box given what you're trying to do).  This equates to up to 1800VA or 2400VA for a resistive load (less for the loads you're running).

If all of your man cave gear is plugged into the 875VA UPS that you linked, that is the limiting factor, not your house wiring.  Get a larger UPS, run two in parallel and have them run different loads, or just use a surge suppressor and skip the battery backup for your less critical loads.

From there, you could also determine if you have multiple circuits supplying power to your garage, but you're a long ways off of having to do that.

Comment: +1 I've ran a LOT of things off of one plug-in before and never tripped a breaker. Just be sure to use cords, surge protectors, and UPSs that can handle it. I had a friend who ran a similar load to yours and one of his power strips failed and nearly started a fire (he caught it in time, but it was thoroughly melted)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have applied it to my garage application, and have successfully solved the power related issues.  The breaker box was located in a maintenance closet outside of my apartment building.  Said maintenance closet houses the breaker boxes for the other 4 units in my building as well.

Answer (score 3):

Your apartment wiring is definitely not the issue, you are overloading your UPS. Either get a beefier one or plug the devices that don't need redundant power into a power strip.

Answer (score 0):

You say with everything on the UPS is at 105% of capacity, but *what capacity is that*?  Since the breaker is not tripping and only the UPS shutting down, it could well be that the outlet has more capacity than the UPS.  Ask the landlord what the outlet is rated for.  It would help to know when the building was built or when the outlet was put in and where this is, but as a wild guess the outlet is probably good for 15 A.  That should be good for 1.6 kW at least with some margin.  Assuming you really meant kW, not kWh (getting units right is important in engineering), then it sounds like a 15 A outlet should do it.

A quick and simple way to get what you want is to only plug in the minimum necessary stuff into the UPS.  Do you really need all the lamps to go thru the UPS?  The TV?  I can see the point to the computer and a monitor and maybe one lamp, but why does the rest of the stuff really need to run accross a power glitch?

Comment: I removed your "short answer".  There's really no need for that sort of thing, especially not in this question.  The OP didn't do anything to warrant that.